# Init method for subclass of PyQt QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt

I'd like to subclass the QTableWidgetItem so that my subclass can have an additional 'id' attribute.

Unfortunately, I'm a little confused because the PyQt docs [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem) show four different **init** methods.

To create my own **init** method for my "QTableWidgetItemWithId" subclass (which would also pass in an extra 'id' argument), should I be using *args, **kwargs?  If so, what would be the correct syntax?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that depends a little on your taste and what you consider readable and also how flexible you want to keep your subclass.
You can add whatever you wish to your constructor and just hand what's needed to QTableWidgetItem's constructor. There are many ways of doing it. I personally try to avoid *args and **kwargs when possible.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableWidgetItem

class ATableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ATableWidgetItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = id

a = ATableWidgetItem(0)
b = ATableWidgetItem(0, QTableWidgetItem.UserType)
c = ATableWidgetItem(0, "text", type=QTableWidgetItem.UserType) 

class AnotherTableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, id):
        super(AnotherTableWidgetItem, self).__init__()
        self.id = id

d = AnotherTableWidgetItem(0)

class YetAnotherTableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):

    def __init__(self, id, text="", type=QTableWidgetItem.Type):
        super(YetAnotherTableWidgetItem, self).__init__(text, type)
        self.id = id

e = YetAnotherTableWidgetItem(0)
f = YetAnotherTableWidgetItem(0, "Hello")
g = YetAnotherTableWidgetItem(0, "Hello", QTableWidgetItem.UserType)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can define as many constructors to your widget item as it suits you. The essential method to override would be the [clone](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtablewidgetitem.html#clone).

Qt has a demo project with a custom QTableWidgetItem descendant here: [Spreadsheet](http://doc.trolltech.org/4.7-snapshot/demos-spreadsheet.html) with custom QTableWidgetItem defined here: [spreadsheetitem.h](http://doc.trolltech.org/4.7-snapshot/demos-spreadsheet-spreadsheetitem-h.html)

hope this helps, regards