# How to subclass QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyside

The following program is a reduced example from an attempt to translate into Python and PySide the spreadsheet example from ["C++  GUI Programming with Qt 4 (2nd Edition)"](http://qt-project.org/books/view/c_gui_programming_with_qt_4_2nd_edition_the_official_c_qt_book). I'm trying to subclass the `QTableWidgetItem` class in order to provide my own type of elements to a `QTableWidget`.

```
import sys

from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

class Cell(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clone(self):
        c = Cell()
        return c

class Spreadsheet(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Spreadsheet, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setItemPrototype(Cell())
        self.clear()

    def clear(self):
        self.setRowCount(0)
        self.setColumnCount(0)
        self.setRowCount(999)
        self.setColumnCount(26)
        for i in range(0, 26):
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(chr(ord('A') + i))
            self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, item)
        self.setCurrentCell(0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    s = Spreadsheet()
    s.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I click on a cell, enter a character, then click on a second cell, the Python interpreter crashes.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284648/init-method-for-subclass-of-pyqt-qtablewidgetitem) and I tried a few variations such as removing `Cell.__init__()` method's arguments or passing `self` to `Cell()` in `clone()`, but always with the same results.

I'm using Python 2.7.3 win32 and PySide 1.1.2 . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks perfectly okay, so there seems to be a bug in PySide. The identical code runs fine using PyQt4.